# Modify Buffer in OpenGL

Tags: performance, opengl, buffer, vbo

I have a modifiable terrain which is stored in a vertex buffer. Because of its large number of vertices, I do not want to upload all vertices again every time the terrain is modified. What I do by now is to split the terrain into smaller chunks so that I only have to recreate the buffer of the area containing the modification of the terrain.

But how can I just add or remove some vertices of an existing buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change data in an existing buffer using `glBufferSubData`

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `glBufferSubData` as datenwolf said, or if you are planning on making a lot of modifications and accessing randomly the data, you may want to map the buffer into client memory using `glMapBuffer` and later unmap it with `glUnmapBuffer.` (Then, based on the access specifiers you chose, you can edit the data as a C array)